# Easy way to count attributes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to count all the attributes that are "true", but using the mark and the model as a filter.

I have a document like this:

```
{
  mark: "bmw",
  model: "compact"
  attr1: true,
  attr2: false,
  attr3: true
}
```

If I were using mysql, I would do something like:

```
SELECT count(attr1=true), count(attr2=true), count(attr3=true) FROM table WHERE mark = 1 AND model = 2
```

And the result would be something like this:

```
{
  attr1: 5,
  attr2: 18,
  attr3: 50
}
```

How can I do this with mongodb? I just need to return the database a line and with this information the count.

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be

```
db.coll.aggregate([    
{
    $match:{"mark":"bmw","model":"compact"}
},{        
    $group:{
        _id:null,
        attr1: {
                $sum: {
               $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$attr1",true] },then: 1,else: 0 }
                }
            },
        attr2: {
                $sum: {
               $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$attr2",true] },then: 1,else: 0 }
                }
            },
        attr3: {
                $sum: {
               $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$attr3",true] },then: 1,else: 0 }
                }
            }                     
        }

    },{
        $project:{
            _id:0,
            attr1:1,
            attr2:1,
            attr3:1,        
        }

    }

    ])
```

result something like this

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "attr1" : 2,
            "attr2" : 1,
            "attr3" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

you can find information 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/
and
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the project and sum as separate operations, which I think is a bit easier to understand:

```
  db.cars.aggregate( [ 
    { $match:{model:'compact' } }, 
    { $project: { attr1:{ $cond: ['$attr1',1,0] }, attr2:{ $cond: ['$attr2',1,0] }, attr3 : { $cond: ['$attr3',1,0] } } },
    { $group: { _id:0, attr1:{$sum:'$attr1'}, attr2:{$sum:'$attr2'}, attr3:{$sum:'$attr3'} } } 
  ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

@bamo
Well, it works. Thank u.

You can turn the result into an object and not an array ?

Like this:

```
{
    "attr1" : 2,
    "attr2" : 1,
    "attr3" : 3
}
```

Only that.

I am using nodejs, I can just do:

```
 var objectInfo = response.result[0]; // first index
```

But if there is any way then return the object and not an array, it would be much better

Comment: Nice! The aggregation result is an array. Can you accept my answer with tick?

Comment: Sure, thank u my friend. U save my day, can u give me ur google plus profile, linkedin ? :)

Comment: Check my info , I don t know if I can put my LinkedIn here